# how to daemonize a script

Tags: linux, daemon

I am trying to use `daemon` on Ubuntu, but I am not sure how to use it even after reading the man page.

I have the following testing script `foo.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    echo 'hi' >> ~/hihihi
    sleep 10
done
```

Then I tried this command but nothing happened:

```
daemon --name="foo" -b ~/daemon.out -l ~/daemon.err -v -- foo.sh
```

The file `hihihi` was not updated, and I found this in the errlog:

```
20161221 12:12:36 foo: client (pid 176193) exited with 1 status
```

How could I use the `daemon` command properly?

Comment: Take a look at nohup. nohup script .sh & Very efficient and simple

Comment: I have no access to an Ubuntu system to test it, but you could try to start a shell to interpret `foo.sh`: `daemon ... /bin/sh ~/foo.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, most `daemon` or `deamonize` programs change the current dir to root as part of the daemonization process. That means that you **must** give the full path of the command:

```
daemon --name="foo" -b ~/daemon.out -l ~/daemon.err -v -- /path/to/foo.sh
```

If it still did not work, you could try to specify a shell:

```
daemon --name="foo" -b ~/daemon.out -l ~/daemon.err -v -- /bin/bash -c /path/to/foo.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to use daemon command in bash. You can daemonize your script manually. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# At first you have to redirect stdout and stderr to /dev/null
exec >/dev/null
exec 2>/dev/null

# Fork and go to background
(
while true; do
    echo 'hi' >> ~/hihihi
    sleep 10
done
)&
# Parent process finished but child still working
```